# @Version from org.springframework.data.mybatis.annotations.Version does not get incremented by 1 on update due to condition that break the query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mybatis

### Description

In a Spring Boot 1.5.9 application,

I am using `org.springframework.data.mybatis.annotations.Version` annotation within an `@Entity` on `version` attribute to get a version incremented on each update, but it keep breaking my application.

The error is:

```
 update effect 0 row, maybe version control lock occurred.
```

I can see that the request end with:

```sql
"version"="version"+1,
where 
"id"=21
 and "version"=null
```

`and "version"=null` cause the whole request to edit `0 row`.

This is an example of entity:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "cm_company_postal_address"
(
    "id"                      BIGSERIAL    NOT NULL,
    "note"                    VARCHAR(255)          DEFAULT NULL,
    "city"                    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "postal_code"             BIGINT                DEFAULT NULL,
    "c_ref_country_id"        BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    "cm_company_id"              BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    "street_address_line1"   VARCHAR      NOT NULL,
    "street_address_line2"   VARCHAR               DEFAULT NULL,
    "post_box"                VARCHAR(20)           DEFAULT NULL,
    "version"                 BIGINT                DEFAULT NULL,
    "created_date_time"       TIMESTAMPTZ           DEFAULT NULL,
    "created_by_id"           BIGINT                DEFAULT NULL,
    "last_modified_date_time" TIMESTAMPTZ           DEFAULT NULL,
    "last_modified_by_id"     BIGINT                DEFAULT NULL,
    "deleted"                 BOOLEAN      NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT company_id_fk FOREIGN KEY ("cm_company_id") REFERENCES "cm_company" ("id")
);
```

This is the java class:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import org.springframework.data.mybatis.annotations.Column;
import org.springframework.data.mybatis.annotations.Condition;
import org.springframework.data.mybatis.annotations.Conditions;
import org.springframework.data.mybatis.annotations.Entity;
import static org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.Type.CONTAINING;

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties("new")
@Entity(table = "cm_company_postal_address")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class PostalAddress {
    @Id(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    @Version
    private Integer version;
    @CreatedDate
    @JsonUnwrapped
    @JdbcType(TIMESTAMP)
    private Instant createdDateTime;
    @LastModifiedDate
    @JsonUnwrapped
    @JdbcType(TIMESTAMP)
    private Instant lastModifiedDateTime;
    @CreatedBy
    private Long createdById;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private Long lastModifiedById;
    @JsonProperty(value = "deleted")
    private Boolean deleted = false;
    @Column(name = "cm_company_id")
    private Long companyId;
    private String city;
    private Long postalCode;
    private Long countryId;
    private String streetAddressLine1;
    private String streetAddressLine2;
    private String postBox;

}
```

This is my `@Repository` for the presented entity:

```java
import com.kopaxgroup.api.companyManagement.domain.postalAddress.geography.PostalAddress;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnExpression;
import org.springframework.data.mybatis.repository.support.MybatisRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface PostalAddressRepository extends MybatisRepository<PostalAddress, Long> {

}
```

This is the service interface for the same entity:

```java
import com.kopaxgroup.api.companyManagement.domain.postalAddress.geography.PostalAddress;
import org.springframework.data.support.CrudService;


public interface PostalAddressService extends CrudService<PostalAddress, Long> {

}
```

And it's implementation:

```java
import com.kopaxgroup.api.companyManagement.domain.postalAddress.geography.PostalAddress;
import com.kopaxgroup.api.companyManagement.repository.PostalAddressRepository;
import com.kopaxgroup.api.companyManagement.service.PostalAddressService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.support.AbstractCrudService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PostalAddressServiceImpl extends AbstractCrudService<PostalAddressRepository, PostalAddress, Long> implements PostalAddressService {

    @Autowired
    public PostalAddressServiceImpl(PostalAddressRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }
```

And this is how I update the entity:

```java
import com.kopaxgroup.api.companyManagement.domain.postalAddress.geography.PostalAddress;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/postal-address")
public class PostalAddressController {

  @Autowired
  private PostalAddressService postalAddressService;

  @PutMapping("/{id}")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
  void modify(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody PostalAddress entity) {
    entity.setId(id);
    postalAddressService.updateIgnore(entity);
  }
}
```

### Expected

I expect to have the `version` column of this entity to be incremented on each update.

### Result

Instead, each update keep a `null` value for version column.

### Question

- How can I prevent `spring-data-mybatis` from appending `and "version"=null` at the end of the request?

### Version

- [spring boot](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/28/spring-boot-1-5-9-available-now): 1.5.9.RELEASE
- [spring-boot-starter-data-mybatis](https://github.com/easybest/spring-data-mybatis/): 1.0.17.RELEASE

Comment: How do you update the persisted entity?

Comment: It's not related to JPA. I use spring-data-mybatis, which is an implementation of spring-data for mybatis, it leverage the same classes and should work. I've updated the question with all the necessary files that answer your question (how it is saved) and added a link to the github repository of `spring-data-mybatis`. Hope it will help to find out.

Comment: No it shouldn't. Mybatis isn't an implementatin of JPA, so trying to mix JPA annotations and expect them to work with MyBatis (regardless the fact that you are using Spring Data MyBatis) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-data has also its own version annotation: `org.springframework.data.annotation.Version`. This annotation is used in spring-data-mybatis lib.

Comment: Hi and thanks, the problem is that I get the following error: https://github.com/easybest/spring-data-mybatis/issues/215

Comment: It is indeed the right class, I have udpated the question, I keep having a weird appended condition `and version=null` at the end of the query that breaks it....

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I would guess that's because the version column defaults to NULL. -> Changing the default to zero (and updating existing records) should fix it.

Comment: I have already tried to set `DEFAULT 0` in my create request. This didn't help. There must be something else that I can configure (perhaps the version = 0 in the class, idk), do you have another hint ? Thanks a lot

Comment: If setting the zero directly for new instances will not help than I'm out of ideas unfortunately.